# UITabbar and UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbar

Hi I'm writing a iOS app with a UITableView and UITabBar. as below,

[image]

I'm adding the tab bar programatically and it sits on a part of my UITableView. So I can't see the last couple of table cells.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Tabbar's height is of 49 pixels, so you have to adjust your table's height in Xib if its in Xib and if its custom table then you have to set it programatically.

Comment: please check your tableview frame.you can adjust your tableView height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the frame of your tableView. In portrait orientation you should decrease it's height, in landscape mode you should deal with it's width.

This code is just a sample, it wasn't tested and may need minor improvements, but it shows an idea:

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
    {
        CGRect r = self.tableView.frame;
        r.size.height-=49;
        self.tableView.frame = r;
    }else
    {
        CGRect r = self.tableView.frame;
        r.origin.x += 49;
        r.size.width-=49;
        self.tableView.frame = r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) my app is Portrait and only needed the first few lines :)

Comment: Landscape part may help you, when you will move to iPad part